# Namspace (.h) between packages

Tags: ros, c++, nodes, packages, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I created a my_gr_namespace.(h/cpp) in **Package_1**. The namespace works well for every single node running under **Package_1**. Now, I am trying to use it in another package (**Package_2**), but it won't work. I have constants in that name space, and when I print them in **Package_2** I get an empty printing. I included the name space this way:

```
 /// Package_2 file: my_package_2.h
#include <Package_1/my_gr_namespace.h>     // written in this format even inside Package_1 nodes

/// prints an empty output, like "My Constant: (empty space)"
std::cout << "My Constant: " << gr::CONSTANT << "\n\n";
```

And the output is empty.

In my **Package_1 CMakeList** I made sure to include the following items to export the name space across ROS:

```
catkin_package()  # where I put Package_2 include folder, and libraries created
# I tried making the namespace files into a library, and then putting them in catkin_package()
add_library()
install(DIRECTORY )  # to mark the namspace cpp and headers for installation
```

And, of course, I copied the files directly into **Package_2** and did:

```
/// copying files inside Package_2 did not work either!!!!!!! What the deuce!?
#include <Package_2/my_gr_namespace.h>
```

I'm not sure what is happening

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242928/namspace-(.h)-between-packages/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to be more of a C++ problem than a cmake/ROS problem.
The reason why I can't see output is because the variable has to be casted to (int). I've never seen that before, though. I'm not what I changed to make behave that way.

Most of my variables are of type "int8_t," and so forth. So if I wanna see output, I gotta do:

```
std::cout << "My Constant: " << (int) gr::CONSTANT << "\n\n";
```

I checked, and the rest of the functions in my packages work well, so I don't have to cast before passing into functions or to publish my variables in a topic.

Dang...glorious C++.

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0